# Enumerate Node.js net.Server connections

Tags: sockets, node.js

Is it possible to loop through all the socket objects corresponding to connections made to a [net.Server](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server) instance in Node.js?

Ultimately, I need to close all connections.  It seems that the only way to do this would be to keep an array of those socket objects as they are created.  Please let me know if there is a built-in way to do this that might be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in list of currently opened sockets in `Node.js`. I even checked the code of `net.Server`, and I didn't find any mechanism to retrieve such a list. Therefore, you need to handle the sockets manually. Even after calling `server.close()`, you should iterate through your own sockets list and close each socket manually to ensure proper cleanup.