# How do I get a list of connected sockets in net.Server?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcpserver

[`net.server.getConnections((err, count) => {...})`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#servergetconnectionscallback) only returns the count of the connection, I can't get each connection. I had thought I could use the following code `for (let socket of server.connections) {...}` inside the callback, but I got the error `TypeError: server.connections is not iterable`.

I search the SO and found a similar question that was asked 10 years ago without an answer so I ask it again, [Enumerate Node.js net.Server connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707363/enumerate-node-js-net-server-connections).

How do I get each connection? Do I have to store each socket myself on `Event: 'connection'` callback? That seems to be **the only way** to do that currently and I have raised a [feature request to nodejs](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/48433)

The similar question was also asked in Python several times, e,g. [How can I keep a list of connected clients in a list in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70048344/how-can-i-keep-a-list-of-connected-clients-in-a-list-in-python) and they all said you have to store it yourself.

Just that Nodejs provides `net.server.getConnections((err, count) => {...})`, which makes me doubt the use case of it.

Comment: You have to store them yourself. There is no reason for any API or framework to do so, and there isn't really any good reason for an application to do so either. Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @user207421 thanks for the comments. But if there is no reason for API to do that, what does it provide `net.server.getConnections`, what is the use case for it ?

Comment: Nothing stopping the server sending messages to clients. That's what the accepted sockets are for. You should not expect every API to be like every other API.

Comment: I need to send a message to its own tcp connection, not broadcast. So I need to get all the connections first then find out which connection this message is for.

Answer (score 0):

The comments I got in [my feature request](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/48433) makes me realize nodejs won't do it for couple of reasons so I have to store each socket myself, e.g.

> Constructing potentially large lists of resources generally feels like an anti-pattern in Node.js, and unless the application code is entirely synchronous, it is prone to race conditions.

The comment also mentioned the possible usage of `net.server.getConnections((err, count) => {...})` ,

> I assume getConnections() to count connections is mostly used as a
> metric in practice, e.g., with Prometheus or so.